# Form not usable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hey guys i am working on a school project and have more or less completed it, but i am having issues loading with my form actually showing the information in the line below, i am still a bit new with html and cannot understand why the form is not showing
up, this is what i have so far, I would assume that my mistake would be somewhere in where my  tag is, because it seems that my HTML is properly processing, but the issue seems to come from my Java.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Simple Bootstrap - V1</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <div class="container">
      <hr/>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="card card-body bg-light">
            <div class="form">
              <div id="timeout" class="alert alert-info">No Start Time<div/>
                <div/>

              <div id="user_message" class="card card-body bg-light"><div/>
             <div class ="alert alert-danger">
               You are going to see this message until timeout is complete

          <div class="label"><div/>

            <hr/>

            <div class="label">Name:<div/>
              <input class="form-control" id="name"></input>

              <hr/>

              <div class="label">Email:<div/>
               <input class="form-control" id="email"></input>
                <hr/>


                <div class="label">City:<div/>
                  <input class="form-control" id="city"></input>



        <div class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_input">Submit Input<div/>


                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <hr/>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-stripped"
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name<th/>
                  <th>Email<th/>
                  <th>City<th/>

                  <tr/>
                  <thead/>
                  <tbody id="table_content">
                    <tr>
                    <td>Name<td/>
                    <td>Email<td/>
                    <td>City<td/>

                    <tr/>

                    </tbody>
              <table/>

              <div>
                <div/>


    </div>
  </body>
</html>


<script>

$ ('#submit_input').click(function() {
  var name= $('#name'.val();
  var name= $('#email').val();
  var name= $('#city').val();



  var tableBody = $('#table_content').html();
  var tableRow = "<tr><td>" + name + "<td/><td> " + email + "<td/><td>" + city + "<td/>><tr/>";
    $('#table_content').html(tableBody + tableRow);
  alert("Your name is" + name ",email" + email ",and you live in" + city);

  alert('#name').val("");
  alert('#email').val("");
  alert('#city').val("");

  var startTimer = 10;

  $('#timeout').html("Time: " + startTimer);

  setTimeout(subtractSecond, 1000);

  function subtractSecond() {
    startTimer = startTimer - 1;
    $('#timeout').html("Time:" + startTimer);

    if (startTimer > 0) {
      setTimeout(subtractSecond, 1000);
    } else {
      $('#user_message').addClass("d-none");
    }
  };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Learn the basics of HTML and Javascript!

This is how to open and close a tag properly:

```html
<div> ... </div>
```

NOT

```html
<div> ... <div />
```

I cant even properly read the document to be able to spot all the errors.

What you put inside the `<script>` Tag is JavaScript, not Java!

Here is your code cleaned up and working as far as I can tell:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Simple Bootstrap - V1</title>
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="card card-body bg-light">
            <div id="timeout" class="alert alert-info">
                No Start Time
            </div>
            <div id="user_message" class="alert alert-danger">
                You are going to see this message until timeout is complete
            </div>

            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="name" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="email" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="city">City:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="city" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_input">
                    Submit Input
                </button>
            </form>

            <table class="table mt-3 table-bordered table-stripped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="table_content">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        $('#submit_input').click(function(e) {
            let time = 10;
            e.preventDefault();

            let name = $('#name').val();
            let email = $('#email').val();
            let city = $('#city').val();

            let tableBody = $('#table_content')[0];
            let tableRow = tableBody.insertRow();
            tableRow.insertCell().append(name);
            tableRow.insertCell().append(email);
            tableRow.insertCell().append(city);

            $('#name').val("");
            $('#email').val("");
            $('#city').val("");

            

            $('#timeout').html('Time: ' + time)

            const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
                if (time > 0) {
                    time--;
                } else {
                    $('#user_message').css("display", "none");
                    clearInterval(intervalID);
                }
                $('#timeout').html('Time: ' + time)
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction, as I said I am new to this and I am glad for the correction, but a follow up question if you do not mind, does this include each and every tag or just <div>, because for instance in my <td>,<tr> and <th>  tags I have also switched the <td/>, is this dash also supposed to be switched to </td> ?

Comment: There are 2 types of Tags: Self-closing-tags and Not-self-closing-tags. Example: `<div> </div>` => NOT self-closing, `<hr />` => SELF CLOSING because it has no content inside.

Comment: I added a fully functional and cleaned up version of your code to my answer, might as well go from there and look exactly which tags are self-closing and which are not.

Comment: Thank you, I will spend the day dissecting this just to understand where I have to improve, the critic and correction is very much appreciated

Comment: Perfect! If you found that I answered your question, consider marking my answer as the accepted one. If you are looking for some more information on HTML, CSS and Javascript, take a look at W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/where_to_start.asp

Answer (score -1):

Please read about HTML closing tags, I have fixed your HTML now you can use your javascript logic.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Simple Bootstrap - V1</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <div class="container">
      <hr/>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="card card-body bg-light">
            <div class="form">
              <div id="timeout" class="alert alert-info">No Start Time</div>
                

              <div id="user_message" class="card card-body bg-light"></div>
             <div class ="alert alert-danger">
               You are going to see this message until timeout is complete
             </div>
          <div class="label"></div>

            <hr/>

            <div class="label">Name:</div>
              <input class="form-control" id="name">

              <hr/>

              <div class="label">Email:</div>
               <input class="form-control" id="email">
                <hr/>


                <div class="label">City:</div>
                  <input class="form-control" id="city">



        <div class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_input">Submit Input</div>


                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <hr/>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-stripped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>City</th>

                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="table_content">
                    <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>City</td>

                    </tr>

                    </tbody>
              </table>

              </div>
                </div>


    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Mateen, from looking at this I see that I have a lot to learn on closing tags in HTML, I will also correct my JavaScript <script> tag for the logic to function. I am still learning and am really glad for the correction along the way

Comment: Glad to know my answer helped you, If you found this answer correct and useful please mark it as the correct answer, Thanks